# Swift OS X root authorization

Tags: swift, macos, shell, security, authentication

I'm writing OS X app that needs to run a lot of shell scripts in different threads asynchronously, and each script needs to be run as root user, so the only full solution for a general problem I've found (using AppleScript) is completely not suitable for me. At this moment, I'm running them like this:

```
func runCommand(command cmd : String) -> String {
    var result = ""

    let task = NSTask()
    task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
    task.arguments = (["-c", cmd])
    task.currentDirectoryPath = "~/"

    let pipe = NSPipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.standardError = pipe
    let handle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
    task.launch()

    let data = NSMutableData()

    while task.running {
        data.appendData(handle.availableData)
    }
    result = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    if !result.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()).isEmpty {
        print("Output for \(cmd) : \(result)")
    }

    return result
}
```

And the command looks like `"\(askpass) sudo -Ak true"` where `askpass` is a file containing password, which is a big security leak. So, the question is: how to make Swift OS X app run as root?

Comment: I should think doing what you asked would be an enormous security leak. No?

Comment: @Feldur, no, I wanna use standard system auth to run my app (and I'm sure my app doesn't run any dangerous code)